# MS Access OpenRecordSet of QueryDef not always returning bound column of lookup

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

Found a number of helpful posts but not it relation to bound columns of lookups.

I have a simple table Tasks with two lookup columns Category and Area. Category is a single column lookup bound to column 1.  Area is a dual column lookup bound to column 2.

tblTasks:
ID, Category (Lookup), Area (Lookup), OtherData...

Category (Lookup RowSource) = select Category FROM tblCategory; (Bound Col 1)

Area (Lookup) RowSource = select ID, Area FROM tblArea; (Bound Col 2)

tblCategory:
ID, Category

tblArea
ID, Area

I have a separate query for each which returns the correct expanded lookup values.

Now via VBA...

When I open the recordset of the Category query I get the category of the lookup returned as expected.

When I open the recordset of The Area query I get the ID of the lookup returned instead of the Area.

I get the impression the bound column must be 1 or bust!!!

Otherwise is there a way to force the bound column of the lookup to be honoured by the openrecordset?

Comment: The bound column is the value that will be saved to record. If you don't want to save the ID then why include it in the RowSource? It certainly doesn't have to be in column 1.

Comment: Using the debugger I can see the BoundColumn property is set to 1 ???

Comment: I have tried manually setting it to 2 but it still returns the first column!!!

Comment: The table is also used by other forms etc.  I am tempted to remove the unwanted column from the lookup on that table as you suggest but what else will I affect. I think it should be safe but this is not my DB!!!

Comment: I see what the problem is.  In tblTask category is short text but area is a number.  Hence why Area lookup is two columns ID and value bound to column two.  So the openrecord set is probably just returning the vaue stored in tbltasks and is not attempting the lookup!  Maybe I have to do the lookup?

Comment: So no i can't remove the first column because of the Area lookup because the column in the task table in numeric.  It uses the Column Width "0cm;2.54cm" notation hide the number and show the string.  I'm sure the recordset can't handle this?

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning. Field type of Category has no bearing on the Area field. BoundColumn does NOT have to be set to 1. If you want to save and display the Area instead of ID: don't include ID in the combobox RowSource, or set its width to zero along with BoundColumn set to 2 (combobox displays the first column where width is not 0), or don't put it in the first column - change order of fields in the RowSource query. These all work fine for me. Post your recordset SQL for analysis.